# Pip for Python 3.4 will not work

Tags: python-3.x, windows-7, pip

I installed Python 3.4 on Windows 7 and was pleased to see it auto-installs with pip.  After adding C:\Python34 and C:\Python34\Scripts to my PATH environment variable, I found that none of my pip installs were working appropriately.  What am I missing here to get these packages to install correctly?  Here is an example of what happens with I attempt to install numpy from the pip log file:

```
Downloading/unpacking numpy
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/
  URLs to search for versions for numpy:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/
  Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.4/n/numpy/numpy-1.0.1.dev3460.win32-py2.4.exe#md5=a55b13b1f141de2aa965d5c5554c4ad8 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/n/numpy/numpy-1.3.0.win32-py2.5.exe#md5=28ee6681b04beb5bfc4bc056417ff087 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/n/numpy/numpy-1.5.1.win32-py2.5-nosse.exe#md5=bfcb66706ebdece6a9680f79f2b643ca (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.0.win32-py2.5.exe#md5=539782c7311d4a3379f66a964159ef11 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.1.win32-py2.5.exe#md5=33686581523c9e7368aefdd63a5952ef (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.2.win32-py2.5.exe#md5=196bac98eebdc953b135a12f0e379d11 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.0.win32-py2.5.exe#md5=05c06781b01326e60ba0921835c44fa0 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.1.win32-py2.5.exe#md5=122d3fd5b78b7c36d4f57863391e2fb0 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/n/numpy/numpy-1.5.0.win32-py2.6.exe#md5=95fd147bb761ca8e2baf34a153586358 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/n/numpy/numpy-1.5.1.win32-py2.6-nosse.exe#md5=267627e760277e5f6a74a83772a4f1d0 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.0.win32-py2.6.exe#md5=e09cd07ba120ed9c84b85c7a188b3bce (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.1.win32-py2.6.exe#md5=67e0c10cf55b713bd27cbba94dee9673 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.2.win32-py2.6.exe#md5=941e4b1b65923addf8a7dc21ec7dbb7e (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.0.win32-py2.6.exe#md5=69b04d57b3d18b266bcce6ecc52d1e06 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.1.win32-py2.6.exe#md5=1b6fd69c28336f399e803a145df29c3d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/n/numpy/numpy-1.5.1.win32-py2.7-nosse.exe#md5=7d6e48b35570c3d83db4cd0a4346b6c1 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.0.win32-py2.7.exe#md5=6f5266d348e5f4d1471a6ae66c26438d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.1.win32-py2.7.exe#md5=30bec16292be262bd78ff1878a7d8953 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.2.win32-py2.7.exe#md5=3757650455a3cb50bf205bbc4c7f4703 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.0.win32-py2.7.exe#md5=7ad31a61947cb91915eb0bfdb01d2ab8 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.1.win32-py2.7.exe#md5=dc11133ce1ce90ceb8f715e879a96e5f (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.1/n/numpy/numpy-1.5.1.win32-py3.1-nosse.exe#md5=13c5ebdd920f2c756602358135fd7196 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.1/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.0.win32-py3.1.exe#md5=917c6b217b3867fe2cbdb788e4e6bb32 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.1/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.1.win32-py3.1.exe#md5=e2b539da620e186df211dbd7339a8993 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.1/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.2.win32-py3.1.exe#md5=0503aa98053340a1a86e0758648e5d75 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.1/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.0.win32-py3.1.exe#md5=7c4afe46ba670cae7e6fada849ffd464 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.1/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.1.win32-py3.1.exe#md5=5c9ebca6a0f513f1f1a34e150575d715 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.2/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.0.win32-py3.2.exe#md5=7863302af8928fb345c420c6af136197 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.2/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.1.win32-py3.2.exe#md5=a6b66602e72436db37e6edbbce269fdf (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.2/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.2.win32-py3.2.exe#md5=b98cc04b20347127e297a99b6114b514 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.2/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.0.win32-py3.2.exe#md5=1b12834a53d3ba543d41399c40b5b791 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.2/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.1.win32-py3.2.exe#md5=651465cacf107d254ddcefcebb47064d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.3/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.0.win32-py3.3.exe#md5=4f20740e7e9d31a9d4c1636a931bc3f9 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.3/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.1.win32-py3.3.exe#md5=6519c7bb198d0caf2913469883a63be9 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp27/n/numpy/numpy-1.8.1-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl#md5=b1127fadbfce9bc0f324ce52fe8efa48 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/) because it is not compatible with this Python
Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp33/n/numpy/numpy-1.8.1-cp33-cp33m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl#md5=d943838035a805925fcbf53204aff1a9 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/) because it is not compatible with this Python
Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp34/n/numpy/numpy-1.8.1-cp34-cp34m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl#md5=31152d55a97cbd655c4eb743d93c4f96 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/) because it is not compatible with this Python
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.3.0.tar.gz#md5=3f7773ff0971a5ebb8591536d8ec7bd6 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.3.0
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.4.1.tar.gz#md5=89b8a56e018b634f7d05c56f17bc4943 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.4.1
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.5.0.tar.gz#md5=3a8bfdc434df782d647161c48943ee09 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.5.0
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.5.1.tar.gz#md5=376ef150df41b5353944ab742145352d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.5.1
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.0.tar.gz#md5=e0993c74cb8e83292e560eac1a9be8e9 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.6.0
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.0.zip#md5=f0ce7ea1a12b3b3480571980af243e48 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.6.0
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.1.tar.gz#md5=2bce18c08fc4fce461656f0f4dd9103e (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.6.1
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.1.zip#md5=462c22b8eb221c78ddd51de98fbb5979 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.6.1
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.2.tar.gz#md5=95ed6c9dcc94af1fc1642ea2a33c1bba (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.6.2
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.2.zip#md5=7e13c931985f90efcfa0408f845d6fee (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.6.2
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.0.tar.gz#md5=4fa54e40b6a243416f0248123b6ec332 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.7.0
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.0.zip#md5=ca27913c59393940e880fab420f985b4 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.7.0
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.1.tar.gz#md5=0ab72b3b83528a7ae79c6df9042d61c6 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.7.1
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.1.zip#md5=9a72db3cad7a6286c0d22ee43ad9bc6c (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.7.1
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.2.tar.gz#md5=6eba32e71bd30cf70b9ea2ef28519d9a (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.7.2
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.2.zip#md5=b9d88d0a57166915cc2e2434466310b5 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.7.2
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.8.0.tar.gz#md5=2a4b0423a758706d592abb6721ec8dcd (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.8.0
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.8.0.zip#md5=6c918bb91c0cfa055b16b13850cfcd6e (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.8.0
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.8.1.tar.gz#md5=be95babe263bfa3428363d6db5b64678 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.8.1
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.8.1.zip#md5=b8b3a99d6ed0913543abb49911205e95 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.8.1
Using version 1.8.1 (newest of versions: 1.8.1, 1.8.1, 1.8.0, 1.8.0, 1.7.2, 1.7.2, 1.7.1, 1.7.1, 1.7.0, 1.7.0, 1.6.2, 1.6.2, 1.6.1, 1.6.1, 1.6.0, 1.6.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.0, 1.4.1, 1.3.0)
Downloading from URL https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.8.1.tar.gz#md5=be95babe263bfa3428363d6db5b64678 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/)
Running setup.py (path:C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_user\numpy\setup.py) egg_info for package numpy
running egg_info
creating pip-egg-info\numpy.egg-info
writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\numpy.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing pip-egg-info\numpy.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\numpy.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\numpy.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
Running from numpy source directory.
warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

reading manifest file 'pip-egg-info\numpy.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching 'tools\py3tool.py'
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'doc\f2py'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\numpy.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
Source in c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_user\numpy has version 1.8.1, which satisfies requirement numpy
Installing collected packages: numpy
Running setup.py install for numpy
Running command C:\Python34\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip_build_user\\numpy\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-spqvbex9-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
F2PY Version 2
blas_opt_info:
blas_mkl_info:
  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python34\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_info:
  libraries  not found in ['C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python34\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python34\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_info:
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python34\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

blas_info:
  libraries blas not found in ['C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python34\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

blas_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

  NOT AVAILABLE

non-existing path in 'numpy\\lib': 'benchmarks'
lapack_opt_info:
lapack_mkl_info:
mkl_info:
  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python34\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Python34\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python34\lib
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Python34\libs
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python34\libs
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_info:
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Python34\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python34\lib
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Python34\libs
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python34\libs
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

lapack_info:
  libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python34\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

lapack_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

  NOT AVAILABLE

running install
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building py_modules sources
creating build
creating build\src.win32-3.4
creating build\src.win32-3.4\numpy
creating build\src.win32-3.4\numpy\distutils
building library "npymath" sources
No module named 'numpy.distutils.msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
Running from numpy source directory.
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_user\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1521: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_user\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1530: UserWarning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_user\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1533: UserWarning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_user\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1427: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_user\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1438: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_user\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1441: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
  warnings.warn(msg)
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
Complete output from command C:\Python34\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip_build_user\\numpy\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-spqvbex9-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'

F2PY Version 2

blas_opt_info:

blas_mkl_info:

libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python34\\libs']

NOT AVAILABLE



openblas_info:

libraries  not found in ['C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python34\\libs']

NOT AVAILABLE



atlas_blas_threads_info:

Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS

libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python34\\libs']

NOT AVAILABLE



atlas_blas_info:

libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python34\\libs']

NOT AVAILABLE



blas_info:

libraries blas not found in ['C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python34\\libs']

NOT AVAILABLE



blas_src_info:

NOT AVAILABLE



NOT AVAILABLE



non-existing path in 'numpy\\lib': 'benchmarks'

lapack_opt_info:

lapack_mkl_info:

mkl_info:

libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python34\\libs']

NOT AVAILABLE



NOT AVAILABLE



atlas_threads_info:

Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS

libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Python34\lib

libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python34\lib

libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\

libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\

libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Python34\libs

libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python34\libs

<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>

NOT AVAILABLE



atlas_info:

libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Python34\lib

libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python34\lib

libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\

libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\

libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Python34\libs

libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python34\libs

<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>

NOT AVAILABLE



lapack_info:

libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python34\\libs']

NOT AVAILABLE



lapack_src_info:

NOT AVAILABLE



NOT AVAILABLE



running install

running build

running config_cc

unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options

running config_fc

unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options

running build_src

build_src

building py_modules sources

creating build

creating build\src.win32-3.4

creating build\src.win32-3.4\numpy

creating build\src.win32-3.4\numpy\distutils

building library "npymath" sources

No module named 'numpy.distutils.msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils

Running from numpy source directory.

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_user\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1521: UserWarning:

Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.

Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting

the ATLAS environment variable.

warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_user\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1530: UserWarning:

Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.

Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting

the BLAS environment variable.

warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_user\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1533: UserWarning:

Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.

Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the

numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting

the BLAS_SRC environment variable.

warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_user\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1427: UserWarning:

Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.

Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting

the ATLAS environment variable.

warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_user\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1438: UserWarning:

Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.

Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting

the LAPACK environment variable.

warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_user\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1441: UserWarning:

Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.

Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the

numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting

the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.

warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)

C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'

warnings.warn(msg)

error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Removing temporary dir C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_user...
Command C:\Python34\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip_build_user\\numpy\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-spqvbex9-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_user\numpy
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 283, in run
requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1435, in install
requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 706, in install
cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\util.py", line 697, in call_subprocess
% (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
pip.exceptions.InstallationError: Command C:\Python34\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip_build_user\\numpy\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-spqvbex9-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_user\numpy
```

Comment: I also have this problem

Answer (score 0):

Link to pip [https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/index.html](http://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/index.html)

pip is run from the command line (Windows PowerShell), not the Python interpreter.

It is a program that installs modules, so you can use them from Python. Once you have installed the module, then you can open the Python shell and do import module name.

The Python shell is not a command line, it is an interactive interpreter. You type Python code into it, not commands

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\Tom> cd /
PS C:\> cd python34
PS C:\python34> pip install wheel
Downloading/unpacking wheel
Installing collected packages: wheel
Successfully installed wheel
Cleaning up...
PS C:\python34>
```

pip Upgrade
python -m pip install -U pip

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\Tom> cd /python34
PS C:\python34> python -m pip install -U pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\python34\lib\site-packages
Cleaning up...
PS C:\python34>
```

Tom

Answer (score 0):

Make sure u installed the latest version of Python 3.4.1 and latest version of JVM version7

Comment: I do but I also have this problem